# Best place to store resolve methods in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I am currently setting up resolves for my admin panel routes and am wondering what the best way of storing them is as ideally I don't want to have my router filled with methods like so:

```
when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'app/private/admin/view.html',
    controller: 'admin',
    resolve: ['$q', '$location', 'api', function($q, $location, api){

        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            session = api.session();

        if(session){
            deferred.resolve(session); 
        } else {
            api.authorise().success(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response); 
            }).error(function(error){
                $location.path('/login');
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;

    }]
})
```

I think an ideal structure would be to store the resolves in the controller I'm using for that route, so something like:

```
when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'app/private/admin/view.html',
    controller: 'admin',
    resolve: adminCtrl.resolve
})
```

However the admin controller is not accessible from the config so this leaves me with having to use a provider which is still going to be messy when expanding my application.

How do you all handle your resolves/is it possible to store it in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use services for the things I want to get resolved:

```
when('/admin', {
templateUrl: 'app/private/admin/view.html',
controller: 'admin',
resolve: { adminData: function(myService) { return myService.list(); } }
});
```

More advanced angular routers like UI-router allow for states to inherit from parent-states. If you want to have a resolve in multiple states you could use inheritance, and define the resolve in your parent-state. (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views).